# Как получить ограниченное числа связей для набора?

Tags: mysql, sql

Немножко запутанный заголовок. Обясню на примере.

У меня 2 таблицы - статьи и рубрики.
У меня есть набор id рубрик.
Мне нужно одним запросом получить по 5 последних статей в каждой рубрике из списка.
База MySQL.

Я не смог придумать ничего другого кроме как использовать `UNION`.

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    article
WHERE
    category_id = :id1
ORDER BY
    date_create DESC
LIMIT
    0, 5
UNION
-- ...
```

Это я туплю или действительно нет другого способа?

Comment: Способов-то дохрена. Но использованный тобой - один из самых эффективных (в смысле - именно для MySQL).

Comment: Например, http://www.sql-ex.ru/help/select16.php

Comment: @msi то что надо. Запрос страшноватый, но значительно быстрее UNION. Спасибо))